# FindAsync search only in primary key or can create complicated queries?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I saw this line of code in ASP.NET Core Identity code [there](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/UserStore.cs):

```
/// <summary>
/// Find a user token if it exists.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="user">The token owner.</param>
/// <param name="loginProvider">The login provider for the token.</param>
/// <param name="name">The name of the token.</param>
/// <param name="cancellationToken">The <see cref="CancellationToken"/> used to propagate notifications that the operation should be canceled.</param>
/// <returns>The user token if it exists.</returns>
protected override Task<TUserToken> FindTokenAsync(TUser user, string loginProvider, string name, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
                => UserTokens.FindAsync(new object[] { user.Id, loginProvider, name }, cancellationToken).AsTask();
```

I am wondering what does this line of code? it just searches for an IdentityToken with a primary key with given values of **user.Id** or **loginProvider** or **name** which can be the result of FindAsync documentation but is not meaningful in application context? or it is searching for a token that has fields with the given values for example generate this query:

```
select * 
from tokens 
where userId = id and loginProvider = "lp" and name = "name"
```

I cannot imagine why we must search for `loginProvider` and name inside `userId` column. If there is any reasonable goal please let me know.

Comment: That's ASP.NET **Core** Identity and Entity Framework **Core**. Please do not confuse technologies, it only makes things harder. Just an FYI, you can turn on query logging in EF Core to see which exact query is being executed, and, in fact, I think the query without parameters is logged by default

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.findasync?view=efcore-5.0 *"Finds an entity with the given primary key values. If an entity with the given primary key values is being tracked by the context, then it is returned immediately without making a request to the database. Otherwise, a query is made to the database for an entity with the given primary key values and this entity, if found, is attached to the context and returned. If no entity is found, then null is returned."*

Comment: If you want to find by non primary key values, look at First[OrDefault], Single[OrDefault] and similar

Comment: I read the documentation already but this query is totally meaningless because the UserId is a Guid field that is linked with the IdentityUser table but other fields are just strings.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The method is just there. Would they add a method to the API if it's "totally meaningless"? Maybe it's used internally. Maybe people who know what they're doing may use it for extensions to the framework. Either way, as usual with questions about the "why" of third-party code, we can only guess. Not on-topic here.

Comment: I don't understand why this query is meaningless?

Comment: `UserTokens` sounds like linking table and these 3 fields form a *compotite* PK. PK columns could be any type - int, `Guid`, string etc.

Comment: *"it just searches for an IdentityToken with a primary key with given values of user.Id or loginProvider or name"* It's not *or* but **and**. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FindAsync returns just one object and it just searches for one result. when it is called on a table with a simple and one column primary key with an array of objects it throws an Argument exception with this message:

> Entity type 'Person' is defined with a single key property, but 2 values were passed to the 'DbSet.Find' method.

you can call the FindAsync method with array parameter just when your primary key is combined with multiple columns.

Also, I checked the AspIdentity database and found that primary key of AspNetUserTokens is defined with multiple columns[image]: